# FutureWarning in using iteritems() in use .iloc() pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image: temp2 DataFrame]

When I use `s.iteritems()` in using `.iloc` I see the below warning:

```
FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead. for item in s.iteritems()
```

While I'm using this function:

```py
temp3 = temp2.iloc[:, 0]
```

I am using python 3.8 and don't know why I'm getting this warning.

I also tried the following:

```py
temp3 = temp2.iloc[:, 0].copy()
temp3 = temp2.loc[:, 0].copy()
temp3 = temp2[0].copy()
```

But it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, I solved my problem with:

```py
temp3 = temp2[0].values
```

But I don't have any idea why I'm getting this warning!

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the module directly, since it gives the line number as 606 in this file (and wait for a fix later from JetBrains):
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2.4\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_utils.py

Change the iteritems to item:

```
def _series_to_str(s, max_items):
    res = []
    s = s[:max_items]
    for item in s.items():
    #for item in s.iteritems(): #bugged on panda 1.5 FutureWarning 
        # item: (index, value)
        res.append(str(item))
    return ' '.join(res)
```